# DropDownlist and List issue in c# ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

this is my Model

```
public class StatModel
    {
            public IEnumerable<int> SelectedItemsRegion { set; get; }

            public List<string> SelectedStats { set; get; } // here I want to put selected Stats (value)

            public List<string> StatsList { set;  get; } //List of Values (stats) to select from it .

        public StatModel() 
            {
                StatsList = new List<string> {"agR", "demandeR" };
           }        

    }
```

This is my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>StatModel</legend>
        @Html.DropDownList("REGIONID", String.Empty)

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStats, Model.StatsList as SelectList)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I got an Error At `@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStats, Model.StatsList as SelectList)`

> CS0039: cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant cast `List<string>` to `SelectList`, you need to initialise a new `SelectList` e.g.

```
public SelectList SelectedStatsList { get; private set; } 

public StatModel() 
{
  StatsList = new List<string> {"agR", "demandeR" };
  SelectedStatsList = new SelectList(StatsList);
}
```

then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStats, Model.SelectedStatsList )
```